# With default typing enabled, is there a way to override the type Jackson outputs?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, unmodifiable

I am serializing a class that includes an unmodifiable list with default typing enabled.  The problem is that the type that Jackson uses is

```
java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList
```

which, for some reason, the deserializer does not know how to handle.

Is there a way to tell Jackson to set the type as

```
java.util.ArrayList
```

which the deserializer does know how to handle, instead?  If possible, I'd like to do it using mixins.

Something like

```
public abstract class ObjectMixin {
    @JsonCreator
    public ObjectMixin(
       @JsonProperty("id") String id,
       @JsonProperty("list") @JsonSerialize(as = ArrayList.class) List<String> list;
    ) {}
}
```

which, unfortunately, does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to start from security risk warning which comes from [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) documentation:

> Notes on security: use "default typing" feature (see
>   `enableDefaultTyping()`) is a potential security risk, if used with
>   **untrusted content** (content generated by untrusted external parties).
>   If so, you may want to construct a custom `TypeResolverBuilder`
>   implementation to limit possible types to instantiate, (using
>   `setDefaultTyping(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.TypeResolverBuilder<?)`).

Lets implement custom resolver:

```
class CollectionsDefaultTypeResolverBuilder extends ObjectMapper.DefaultTypeResolverBuilder {

    private final Map<String, String> notValid2ValidIds = new HashMap<>();

    public CollectionsDefaultTypeResolverBuilder() {
        super(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.OBJECT_AND_NON_CONCRETE);
        this._idType = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS;
        this._includeAs = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY;

        notValid2ValidIds.put("java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList", ArrayList.class.getName());
        // add more here...
    }

    @Override
    protected TypeIdResolver idResolver(MapperConfig<?> config, JavaType baseType, Collection<NamedType> subtypes,
                                        boolean forSer, boolean forDeser) {
        return new ClassNameIdResolver(baseType, config.getTypeFactory()) {
            @Override
            protected String _idFrom(Object value, Class<?> cls, TypeFactory typeFactory) {
                String id = notValid2ValidIds.get(cls.getName());
                if (id != null) {
                    return id;
                }
                return super._idFrom(value, cls, typeFactory);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Now, we can use it as below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MapperConfig;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.NamedType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.TypeIdResolver;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.ClassNameIdResolver;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        mapper.setDefaultTyping(new CollectionsDefaultTypeResolverBuilder());

        Root root = new Root();
        root.setData(Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("1", "b")));
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(root);
        System.out.println(json);
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json, Root.class));
    }
}

class Root {
    private List<String> data;

    public List<String> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<String> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Root{" +
                "data=" + data +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{
  "data" : [ "java.util.ArrayList", [ "1", "b" ] ]
}
Root{data=[1, b]}
```

You can even map it to `List` interface:

```
notValid2ValidIds.put("java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList", List.class.getName());
```

And output would be:

```
{
  "data" : [ "java.util.List", [ "1", "b" ] ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the security caution.  It's not a problem for my use case in that it's internal use only.  The solution worked with one small change.  For some reason `this._includeAs = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY` did not work for me but `this._includeAs = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_ARRAY` does work.